# Fetching all values from a webpage along with user inputs

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

We have key-value pair contents on some of our web pages, and I need to get all of these for logging purposes. There are forms on some of these pages for the user to fill in, so i need to get their values too. It is clear that I need to scan and try to obtain these values when the user clicks submit button, to get the inputs' values too.

1) What i try to get from the page looks like for example `Customer No:` *12345*

2) And there may be some forms on the page like `Customer Name:` ___________ I need to get the value that user provides into this inputs too.

3) Pages are always displayed in Internet Explorer, so I can prepare an activex, another process that uses shdocvw, or I may inject some javascript to fetch these values(at least these are coming to my mind)

4) After all of these, I need to have all values on a page in a form like `{CustomerNo:12345, CustomerName: abcdef}`

I need to prepare something generic, so that it can work on every page of ours. Is there any way to achieve this? Is there any third party software that converts all of a web page(along with user inputs) into a flat XML for example?

Thanks

Comment: What does the page html look like? In particular the areas containing the key-value pairs

Comment: They generally reside in HTML tables. In one tr, key appears in left td, value(or user input element) in right td.